# Fatal error: supernotcalledexception

Tags: android

Could some one please help me with the issues in the below code, as I am getting did not call through `super.onDestroy()`, fatal error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data){
        list_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.listbtn);
        super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, data);
        if (resultcode == 100){
    //*     Intent in3 = getIntent();
            int songnum = data.getExtras().getInt("songindex");
                playsong(songnum);
                player.start();
                play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_aft);
                pause_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_int);
                stop_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_int);
        }
        seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());
    }

    private void playsong(int songnum) {
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(Songlist.get(songnum).get("songname"));
            player.prepare();
            seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());
            seekUpdation();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    Runnable run = new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        seekUpdation(); 
    } 
    }; 
    public void seekUpdation() { 
        seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition()); 
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000); 
    } 
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        Log.d(TAG, "Player Crushed");
    }    
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
    switch (view.getId()) { 
    case R.id.play:
        text_shown.setText("Playing..."); 
        player.start();
        pause_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_int);
        stop_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_int);
        play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_aft);
    break; 
    case R.id.pause: 
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.pause(); 
            text_shown.setText("Paused..."); 
            play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_int);
            pause_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_aft);
        }

    break;
    case R.id.stop:
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
            text_shown.setText("Stopped...");
            play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_int);
            pause_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_int);
            stop_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_aft);
            player.prepareAsync();
            player.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            try {
                player.prepare();
                player.seekTo(0);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    break;
    } 
}
}
```

**Logcat**

```
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.musicplay/com.example.musicplay.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2690)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:964)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-26 23:17:37.993: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 23:19:31.443: E/MediaPlayer(481): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
08-26 23:19:31.443: E/MediaPlayer(481): error (-38, 0)
08-26 23:19:31.487: E/MediaPlayer(481): Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: I am not sure which line is causing this error, could you please let me know how to locate it?

Comment: Read the stacktrace. (Or else post it here.)

Comment: Hi i have posted the error log in answer column

Comment: Is it a typo that you are missing the closing bracket for `onCreate()`. If not, then I would think you would be having a whole lot of compile errors.

Comment: Sorry yar its a typo i have just copied only the mail content...

Comment: Please don't edit out your original code and/or errors. It makes the question useless for others with your original problem. If you have a new problem that you can't figure out then please post a new question with relevant code and errors.

Comment: Ok just a sec i will provide the complete code

Comment: No! The correct thing to do is to accept the answer that helped you with this problem by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Then if you have a new question, then make it a new post. But try reading your logcat first and seeing what the problem may be

Comment: @RazerWaran You **need** to stop editing this as you have been doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `super.onDestroy()` **last** in your own `onDestroy()` method:

```
public void onDestroy(){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    Log.d(TAG, "Player Crushed");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

My hypothesis is that the `MediaPlayer` requires the `Activity`'s context, so the `Activity` must be destroyed after the calls to `stop()` and `release()`.

Comment: Actually, I believe that the correct approach is to do so first in the method.  As this takes care of all necessary closures before any code that the user might call could go firing exceptions.

Comment: @JaySnayder Go ahead and try it. Copy and paste the OP's code, compile and run to reproduce the error, then make this fix and compile and run again.

Comment: Thanks a lot man i have another error in the same code

Comment: @RazerWaran No thanks, heh.  Not necessary.  I'll take your word that in this case it will matter for the way that his code is designed.

Comment: Hi Jay same code i am getting seekupdation fatal error, could you please help me with this

Comment: @RazerWaran The way this site works is 1 question, 1 answer. If Code-Apprentice helped you to fix this 1 question, then you accept his 1 answer. Then create a new question with the new problem. Good luck and thanks for following the rules.

Comment: @RazerWaran If this fixed your error, please accept my answer by clicking the check mark. If you have another question, please simply start a new one.