# How to fix 'SuperNotCalledException" of onDestroy?

Tags: java, android, exception, super

I'm using onDestroy inside a fragment to make sure a Handler (used to animate a button) is stopped when exiting the app, as the code below shows:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy () {
    if (anim1 !=null && run1 !=null) {
        anim1.removeCallbacks(run1);
    }
    super.onDestroy ();
}
```

anim1 is the Handler; run1 is the Runnable.

The code *works as intended* in my test devices (running various Android versions, but not 6.0 or 8.1 - this will be an issue, as you'll see). It also works for the vast majority of users, judging by Google Console reports and general feedback.

In other words, if the user attempts to leave the app (or move to another fragment) while the Handler/Runnable are still there, there is no exception thrown and the `anim1.removeCallbacks(run1);` is triggered as expected with no errors.

Looking at the reports from Google Console, however, a few Android 6.0 and 8.1 users have had a **SuperNotCalledException** (log provided below). Numerically, 8.1 users seem to be more affected compared to 6.0

I know that the problem is in my implementation of onDestroy because this error (SuperNotCalledException) began showing up on Google Console only *after* I implemented the code above. Before I was getting a NPE because of the Handler still running while the app exited (this error no longer exists).

I'm only getting a few error reports for this, so apparently it only affects a few users. But I wonder what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

I've already looked at other similar questions, such as these:

[Fatal error: supernotcalledexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513955/fatal-error-supernotcalledexception)

[NullPointer at OnDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895171/nullpointer-at-ondestroy)

but they don't seem to be related to my issue. 
`super.onDestroy` is in my code, and it comes at the end. The logcat isn't too revealing (to me at least) either:

```
Huawei Honor 7A (HWDUA-M), Android 8.1
Report 1 of 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:4679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:4697)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1837)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6861)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:450)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy (Fragment.java:2590)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1566)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1759)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1836)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3244)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy (FragmentManager.java:3235)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy (FragmentController.java:265)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy (FragmentActivity.java:390)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy (AppCompatActivity.java:209)
  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy (Activity.java:7335)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy (Instrumentation.java:1249)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:4666)
```

Any idea what I could try to troubleshoot the issue further? I feel a bit baffled, because it's literally 3 lines of code causing the problem, and I can't figure out how else to put them together.

If you need any further details or code, let me know and I'd be happy to provide them.

Comment: Are you on the latest edition of the Support Library implementation of fragments? The AndroidX implementation may be newer yet, though you seem to be using the Support Library. Also, are you sure you want to be waiting until `onDestroy()` to clean this up? Perhaps `onDestroyView()` would work better for this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use onDestroyView(), I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a try. It's a bit hard for me to replicate/troubleshoot the problem because, as I said, it seems to only affect a few users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding my solution as an answer in case someone else finds it useful.
Turns out, the problem wasn't *in this particular* fragment and code, but in another similar fragment.

I had copied/pasted the code in all of them, but at some point, somewhere, the code I discovered searching was like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy () {
    if (anim1 !=null && run1 !=null) {
    anim1.removeCallbacks(run1);
    super.onDestroy ();
    }
}
```

Since `super.onDestroy ()` accidentally ended up inside the if-statement, it was unreachable whenever the activity was destroyed while `anim1` and/or `run1` were null. Detecting it wasn't made easier by the fact that the logcat doesn't report on *which* fragment the exception occurred.

The morality of the tale is, always check all instances of your code, even if you have copied/pasted it.